# Can't setup AP with Ralink RT5370 and hostapd

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to use https://github.com/sabhiram/raspberry-wifi-conf on my raspberry pi 2 with a RT5370 wifi dongle, but I can't see the AP in the wifi list.

when I try to run hostapd directly via the terminal, I get this :

```
$ hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf                                                                                                                 
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf                                                                                                                                 
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode                                                                                                                                      
nl80211 driver initialization failed.                                                                                                                                         
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
```

I'm running a rapsbian jessy with hostapd v 2.3

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your wlan0 interface wasn't already up, just do a:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
```

before calling hostapd.